# Use Etrade API's query parameters returns unauthorized (401)

Tags: python, https, etrade-api

I cannot understand how to properly use the query parameters using Etrade's production API. Regardless of the query parameter used, the response is always unauthorized. Here's the [documentation](https://apisb.etrade.com/docs/api/account/api-portfolio-v1.html) relevant to this example. Most of the code is taken from the Python example on this [page](https://developer.etrade.com/home).

I receive a 200 response without the parameter and 401 when adding the parameter `sortOrder=ASC`.

```
import configparser
from rauth import OAuth1Service
import webbrowser


# loading configuration file
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read("etrade_python_client/config.ini")

etrade = OAuth1Service(
        name="etrade",
        consumer_key=config["DEFAULT"]["PROD_KEY"],
        consumer_secret=config["DEFAULT"]["PROD_SECRET"],
        request_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/request_token",
        access_token_url="https://api.etrade.com/oauth/access_token",
        authorize_url="https://us.etrade.com/e/t/etws/authorize?key={}&token={}",
        base_url="https://api.etrade.com")

request_token, request_token_secret = etrade.get_request_token(params={"oauth_callback": "oob", "format": "json"})
authorize_url = etrade.authorize_url.format(etrade.consumer_key, request_token)
webbrowser.open(authorize_url)
```

The previous line opens a web browser which I navigate to and copy the code and store it as `text_code`.

```
text_code = "<copy-code-from-web-browser>"
session = etrade.get_auth_session(request_token, request_token_secret, params={"oauth_verifier": text_code})

# get account info
url_account = "https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/list.json"
data_account = session.get(url_account, header_auth=True).json()

# store account id key
account_id_key = res["AccountListResponse"]["Accounts"]["Account"][0]["accountIdKey"]

# get portfolio and specify sortOrder
url_portfolio = "https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/{}/portfolio?sortOrder=ASC".format(account_id_key)
data_portfolio = session.get(url_portfolio, header_auth=True)
print(data_portfolio)
```

```
>>> <Response [401]>
```

```
# get portfolio and do not specify sort order    
url_portfolio = "https://api.etrade.com/v1/accounts/{}/portfolio".format(account_id_key)
data_portfolio = session.get(url_portfolio, header_auth=True)
print(data_portfolio)
```

```
>>> <Response [200]>
```

Has anyone else ran into this issue? I'm thinking I must not be passing the query parameters correctly.

Comment: In your example it says you get a 200 for a request to portfolio. The 401 when adding sortOrder parameter. Confirmed?

Comment: @srn that is correct.  I'll edit the post to make it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation on their site seems to not tell how to do that, but they provide an example python script which I hoped would include hints. And it kind of does, but I can't verify them as I don't have such an account. Please let us know, if either suggestion worked or you found another solution.

While the example for *a get* to the portfolio endpoint they give looks like:

```
def portfolio(self):    
    # URL for the API endpoint
    url =self.base_url + "/v1/accounts/" + self.account["accountIdKey"] + "/portfolio.json"

    # Make API call for GET request
    response = self.session.get(url, header_auth=True)
```

There are other examples such as a get to balance, which might be relevant to your question:

```
def balance(self):
    # URL for the API endpoint
    url = self.base_url + "/v1/accounts/" + self.account["accountIdKey"] + "/balance.json"

    # Add parameters and header information
    params = {"instType": self.account["institutionType"], "realTimeNAV": "true"}
    headers = {"consumerkey": config["DEFAULT"]["CONSUMER_KEY"]}

    # Make API call for GET request
    response = self.session.get(url, header_auth=True, params=params, headers=headers)
```

Here we can see that `params=params` would be accept.

So what I'd try would be something like this for your request:

```
# get portfolio and specify sortOrder
url_portfolio = "https://api.etrade.com/v1/account/{}/portfolio".format(account_id_key)
params = {'sortOrder':'ASC'}
data_portfolio = session.get(url_portfolio, params=params, header_auth=True)
print(data_portfolio)
```

Also, I'd consider the possibility that for `sortOrder` to be used correctly, you may need to provide a param for `sortBy` as well (acceptable values are in the doc you linked).

Comment: Wonderful.  As you demonstrated, passing the parameters as a dictionary into the get() method solves the issue.

Comment: Nice, I'll update my answer to clean up the speculative part then.